# How to change Label to Textbox in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

How to change UILabel to UITextField dynamically in iOS?

I want to change Label to TextField, Dropdown list, etc... on click edit button.

Help me to fix this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a TextField under a UILabel at a same position and dimension, then when user taps edit button, you should hide the label, make textfield visible and bring it to top, this is a easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `UILabel` on top of `UITextField` and you can use below code to handle edit and normal mode.

Normal Mode:

```
self.lbl.hidden = NO;
self.textfield.enabled = NO;
self.textfield.hidden = YES;
```

Edit Mode :

```
self.lbl.hidden = YES;
self.textfield.enabled = YES;
self.textfield.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change it.  But since you are new to iOS, I would suggest you but the controls you want at design time.  Then show/hide the proper control at the proper time.

Once you have perfect your application, you can learn how to add/remove controls at runtime for version 2 of your app.